# Third party bundle imports and uses any version of a package exported by system bundle

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

I have two third party bundles that both depend on the javax.transaction package. This package is exported by the system bundle as version 0.0.0. One of the bundles imports any version of the package and declares it as a uses-constraint on its exported package. The other bundle explicitly requires version 1.1.0. This package is provided by a different bundle.

My own bundle requires both third party bundles. However, since the system bundle is resolved first, the third party bundle that accepts any version is wired against version 0.0.0. As a result, a package uses conflict arises.

What are the options to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**Options 1:**

Append a version to Import-Package in every bundle where javax.transaction is imported. I would not suggest this. :)

**Option 2:**

Do not import the javax.transaction package in the boot delegation. That is what we do, too. You can set the packages that should be imported via the org.osgi.framework.system.packages system variable. To see an example, look for the name in the variable in [this pom](https://github.com/everit-org/osgi-liquibase-bundle/blob/b739a9ce78044b8e1745c2f7cded8be3145a20a1/tests/pom.xml) file. There is an example for felix and one for equinox.

With this option, you might have the problem that javax.sql depends on javax.transaction.xa package. In that case, you can use javax.sql from a bundle that is available [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.everit.osgi.bundles%7Corg.everit.osgi.bundles.javax.sql%7C4.0.0%7Cbundle) (JDBC version 4.0.0). Of course, you must exclude javax.sql packages from the boot delegation as well (the examples exclude them).

As javax.transaction.xa is only used from javax.sql and javax.sql is not used from any other 
JDK packages, these packages can be safely separated and used from bundles.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two bundles (the system bundle and some other bundle) that export this package. If the contents of the package is the same in both cases, the easiest solution is to only provide it once. Since one of your consuming bundles needs at least version 1.1.0 you should either make sure you export at least that version, or change your consumer to accept any version.

So you can either remove the "other bundle" that provides the package (or modify it in case it provides more than just this package) or you can modify the list of packages that the framework exports. There is a property in the specification to do this called "org.osgi.framework.system.packages" that lists all these packages, so you can make a new list that exludes this package.

Like Balazs says, I would stay away from boot delegation, but judging from your description you were not using that.

Comment: Do you know where I can set this property for Tycho? Also, is there a way so that I can have it configured for both Tycho and Eclipse from one location?

Comment: Try setting it as a system property. I'm not familiar with Tycho (I use Bndtools for OSGi development in Eclipse) but in general, if you can find a way to set system properties, it will work.